# Javascript calculations and postbacks

Tags: asp.net, javascript, math, calculated-field

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app where I'm using a Wizard to take the client through a large series of steps.

One of the steps includes calculating a bunch of numbers on the fly... the numbers calculate properly but when I click "next" and then go back again... some of the numbers are not retained.

Here is the calculation function

```
function CalculateFields() {

    txtSellingPrice = document.getElementById('<%=txtSellingPrice.ClientID %>');
    //I get all of the elements like this...
    //...   

    var regexp = /[$,]/g;


    //Empty value checks
    SellingPrice = (SellingPrice == "" ? "$0" : SellingPrice);
    BalanceSheet = (BalanceSheet == "" ? "$0" : BalanceSheet);
    DownPayment = (DownPayment == "" ? "$0" : DownPayment);
    susearn = (susearn == "" ? "$0" : susearn);
    susrev = (susrev == "" ? "$0" : susrev);
    balmult = (balmult == "" ? "$0" : balmult);
    goodmult = (goodmult == "" ? "$0" : goodmult);
    sellmult = (sellmult == "" ? "$0" : sellmult);


    //Replace $ with String.Empty
    SellingPrice = txtSellingPrice.value.replace(regexp, "");
    BalanceSheet = txtBalanceSheet.value.replace(regexp, "");
    DownPayment = txtDownPayment.value.replace(regexp, "");
    susearn = txtSusEarn.value.replace(regexp, "");
    susrev = txtSusRev.value.replace(regexp, "");
    balmult = txtBalanceMult.value.replace(regexp, "");
    goodmult = txtGoodwillMult.value.replace(regexp, "");
    sellmult = txtSellingPriceMult.value.replace(regexp, "");


    //Set the new values
    txtGoodWill.value = "$" + (SellingPrice - BalanceSheet);
    txtBalance.value = "$" + (SellingPrice - DownPayment);
    txtSellingPriceMult.value = "$" + SellingPrice;
    txtGoodwillMult.value = "$" + (SellingPrice - BalanceSheet);
    txtBalanceMult.value = "$" + BalanceSheet;

    if (chkTakeBack.checked == 1) {
        txtVendorTakeBackPercentage.value = Math.round((SellingPrice - DownPayment) / SellingPrice * 100);
    }
    else {
        txtVendorTakeBackPercentage.value = "0";
    }

    if (!(susearn == "") && !(susearn == "0") && !(susearn == "$0")) {
        txtSusEarnPercentage.value = Math.round(susearn / susrev * 100);
        txtBalanceMultPercentage.value = Math.round(balmult / susearn);
        txtGoodwillMultPercentage.value = Math.round(goodmult / susearn);
        txtSellingPriceMultPercentage.value = Math.round(sellmult / susearn);
    }
    else {
        txtSusEarnPercentage.value = "0";
        txtBalanceMultPercentage.value = "0";
        txtGoodwillMultPercentage.value = "0";
        txtSellingPriceMultPercentage.value = "0";
    }

}
```

all of these calculate properly and retain their value across postbacks

```
    txtGoodWill.value = "$" + (SellingPrice - BalanceSheet);
    txtBalance.value = "$" + (SellingPrice - DownPayment);
    txtSellingPriceMult.value = "$" + SellingPrice;
    txtGoodwillMult.value = "$" + (SellingPrice - BalanceSheet);
    txtBalanceMult.value = "$" + BalanceSheet;
```

These ones however do not retain their value across postbacks

```
        if (chkTakeBack.checked == 1) {
            txtVendorTakeBackPercentage.value = Math.round((SellingPrice - DownPayment) / SellingPrice * 100);
        }
        else {
            txtVendorTakeBackPercentage.value = "0";
        }

        if (!(susearn == "") && !(susearn == "0") && !(susearn == "$0")) {
            txtSusEarnPercentage.value = Math.round(susearn / susrev * 100);
            txtBalanceMultPercentage.value = Math.round(balmult / susearn);
            txtGoodwillMultPercentage.value = Math.round(goodmult / susearn);
            txtSellingPriceMultPercentage.value = Math.round(sellmult / susearn);
        }
        else {
            txtSusEarnPercentage.value = "0";
            txtBalanceMultPercentage.value = "0";
            txtGoodwillMultPercentage.value = "0";
            txtSellingPriceMultPercentage.value = "0";
        }
```

The `txtVendorTakeBackPercentage` always comes back BLANK
and the other three always come back as `0`

I'm firing these functions by using the `onkeyup` event within the form fields.

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        txtSellingPrice.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtBalanceSheet.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtDownPayment.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtSusRev.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtSusEarn.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
    End If
```

any thoughts/help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
My page load event looks something like this...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    'Prepair page for advanced validation'
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    If Not cs.IsOnSubmitStatementRegistered(Me.[GetType](), "PrepareValidationSummary") Then _
        cs.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.[GetType](), "PrepareValidationSummary", "CheckForm()")

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        'Part of the client side math'
        txtSellingPrice.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtBalanceSheet.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtDownPayment.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtSusRev.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
        txtSusEarn.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "CalculateFields()")
```

My actual aspx page has got over 2400 lines, so I'm not going to post the whole thing.  Here is a section where the percentage fields are not retaining their values.

```
  <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="AlignRight">
                            Average Annual Sustainable Earnings (ebitda) estimated&nbsp;
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtSusEarnPercentage" runat="server" Enabled="False" MaxLength="3"
                                Width="20px" TruncateLeadingZeros="True" />
                            %
                        </td>
                        <td class="AlignRight">
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtSusEarn" runat="server" AutoFormatCurrency="True" DecimalPlaces="2"
                                MaxLength="9" Width="92px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Image ID="HelpEBITDA0" runat="server" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/help.gif" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="AlignRight">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td class="AlignRight">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="AlignRight">
                            Balance Sheet / Net Asset Value as earnings multiple&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtBalanceMultPercentage" runat="server" Enabled="False" MaxLength="3"
                                Width="20px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="AlignRight">
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtBalanceMult" runat="server" AutoFormatCurrency="True" DecimalPlaces="2"
                                MaxLength="9" Width="92px" Enabled="False" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="AlignRight">
                            Goodwill Value as earnings multiple&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtGoodwillMultPercentage" runat="server" Enabled="False" MaxLength="3"
                                Width="20px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="AlignRight">
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtGoodwillMult" runat="server" AutoFormatCurrency="True" DecimalPlaces="2"
                                MaxLength="9" Width="92px" Enabled="False" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="AlignRight">
                            Proposed Selling Price as earnings multiple&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtSellingPriceMultPercentage" runat="server" Enabled="False"
                                MaxLength="3" Width="20px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="AlignRight">
                            <ew:NumericBox ID="txtSellingPriceMult" runat="server" AutoFormatCurrency="True"
                                DecimalPlaces="2" MaxLength="9" Width="92px" Enabled="False" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Here is the form when I fill it in
<strike>before.png</strike>

And here is the form after I hit "next" and then "previous"
<strike>after.png</strike>

#### Edit

Images are long gone, sorry.

Comment: It may be worthwhile adding some of your markup - especially the part that contains the controls that do not retain their values after the postback.

Comment: @Cœur oh man this question is so old now, those images are long gone.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net does not maintain the values of readonly or disabled textboxes ... to work around this use :

`TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");` instead of `TextBox1.ReadOnly = true;`

and

`TextBox1.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");` instead of `TextBox1.Enabled = false;`

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this yet but it's an excellent observation/suggestion.  I'll check it out as soon as I can.